# Sliding session and algorithm adopted for reissue cookie

Tags: session, caching, wif, thinktecture-ident-server

I have an issue about the heuristic adopted by thinktecture sliding session and discovered that [microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.slidingexpiration.aspx) implements the same algorithm on forms authentication using sliding session. They update the session cookie only if the half of the expiration time has passed.

I know that renewal of the session cookie is not for free, but I could not find any place that explain how costly it is.

Imagine a scenario that the system admin can configure the expiration timeout due innactivity and he configures the timeout with 20 minutes. An user logs on system at 10:00 and at 10:09 he makes a request, the sys admin expects the session expires at 10:29, but what will happen is that the user will be redirected to the login page at 10:20.

I could simply remove this algorithm, but I need first to understand what are the consequences. Could a lot of page callbacks be a problem?
Has anyone dealt with this scenario? I need that timings that are accurate.